# Accessing htmlcontrols from codebehind

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

Is there any way to access html controls in ASP.net code behind.

Some control similar to Findcontrol() to access the html controls. I am using

```
 HtmlSelect htsel1;

    htsel1 = (HtmlSelect)FindControl("stage_txt1");
```

but htsel1 is returning null.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `runat=server` and an `ID`.

aspx:

```
<select id="stage_txt1" runat=server"  >
    <option value="1">stage 1</option>
    <option value="2">stage 2</option>
    <option value="3">stage 3</option> 
    <option value="4">stage 4</option>
</select>
```

codebehind:

```
HtmlSelect myDdl = (HtmlSelect)FindControl("stage_txt1");
```

or just use the servercontrols like `Panel` instead of `div` or `TextBox` instead of `HtmlInputText` or `DropDownList` instead of `HtmlSelect` and so on.

If the page is the `NamingContainer`( they are not nested in child-controls like `Repeater`) you can also access them directly without to use `FindControl`.

```
HtmlSelect myDdl = this.stage_txt1;
```

Comment: In the page load event I am loading the dropdown from code behind like this + "<select id=\"stage_txt" + i + "\" class=\"enbldbox\" runat=\"server\" >" + "</select>" + "<img alt=\"Required\" id=\"stage_txt_ast" + i + "\" src=\"astrek.png\" width=\"10px\" height=\"10px\"" + "class=\"astrk\" />" + "</td></tr>"; } maindiv.InnerHtml = dyntable; and I am trying to access this dropdown in a button click and I am unable to get the control from code behind

Comment: @VenkateshKaramala: Don't add text and expect that it will be accessible from serverside. That simply does not work. If you need to add controls dynamically either use  webdatabound controls like `Repeater` which can also create html-controls(preferred) or create instances of controls like `HtmlSelect` and add them to the page's control-collection.

Answer (score 1):

You need the **runat="server"** attribute. For instance:

```
<div id="myServerSideDiv" runat="server"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just give the html element a runat="server" and id attribute and the control will be accessable from code behind